# BETWEEN @Start and @End Date; Not pulling in records which fall beyond the date

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Currently working on a t-sql query which is supposed to get a list of all records that fall between the current fiscal year (we use 4-4-5 calendar). 
The record's start and end date are 06/02/2018, 31/07/2020.

The date I am filtering for is:

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATE = '12-29-2018';
DECLARE @EndDate DATE = '12-31-2019';
```

The condition I have in my where clause is:

```
 AND
          (

          (o.Revenue_Start_Date__c >= @StartDate AND  o.Revenue_End_Date__c <= @EndDate) OR (o.Revenue_End_Date__c >= @StartDate AND  o.Revenue_End_Date__c <= @EndDate)
          )
```

I have tried variations of BETWEEN as well. Any idea what I may be doing wrong and how do I get a list of all records to be included if it falls within the coresponding dates.

ANSWER:

```
AND  (  -- Starts Within range
  ( o.Revenue_Start_Date__c 
    BETWEEN @StartDate
    AND     @EndDate
  )
OR  -- Ends within range
  (
    o.Revenue_End_Date__c
    BETWEEN @StartDate
    AND     @EndDate
   )
OR    -- SPANS Range
   (
     o.Revenue_Start_Date__c < @StartDate
     AND
     o.Revenue_End_Date__c > @EndDate  
    )
    )
```

This seems to be working for me just now.

Comment: The general check for overlapping ranges is `Start1 <= End2 and Start2 <= End1`. Refer to the [`overlap`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/overlap/info) tag wiki for an explanation.

Answer (score 1):

For fall through cases, this should work.

`o.Revenue_Start_Date__c <= @EndDate AND  o.Revenue_End_Date__c >=  @StartDate`

[image]

Comment: @ae15 Yes. To me it looks fine. But having two conditions is simpler than several more.

Comment: I have posted a picture as well, showing how does it work. Those are the five cases that your query needs to address. This was shown to me by an enlightened engineer about 10years back :)

Comment: Voted up not just because its right, but because of the sticky-pad picture!

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
(o.Revenue_Start_Date__c < @EndDate AND 
 o.Revenue_End_Date__c >= @StartDate
)
```

This is the logic for overlapping intervals.  Note that the inequalities might be exact or inexact depending on your actual definitions of overlapping.